# python, problem sending push notifications to phone with google firebase (without android application)

Tags: python, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-storage

the code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import messaging
from google.cloud import storage

cred = credentials.Certificate('push-notifier.json')

# Start Firebase Admin SDK
if not firebase_admin._apps:
    default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
        'storageBucket': 'push-notifier-144.appspot.com'
    })
else:
    default_app = firebase_admin.get_app()

# PDF file's name and path 
local_file_path = 'Backend-TOGG.pdf'

# Crete Google Cloud Storage Connection
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('push-notifier.json')
# Choose Storage Bucket 
bucket = client.get_bucket('push-notifier-144')
# Upload the file
blob = bucket.blob('Backend-TOGG')
blob.upload_from_filename(local_file_path)

# Create the file's url
url = f'https://storage.googleapis.com/push-notifier-144.appspot.com/{blob.name}'

# Prepare the push message
message = messaging.Message(
    notification=messaging.Notification(
        title='Price Tracker Analysis has been finished.',
        body='click on here to reach analysis results.',
    ),
    data={
        'url': url
    },
    topic='price_tracker',
    android=messaging.AndroidConfig(
        ttl=86400,
        notification=messaging.AndroidNotification(
            click_action='DOWNLOAD_PDF'
        )
    )
)



# Send Push Notification
response = messaging.send(message, app=default_app)
print('Successfully sent message:', response)
```

The code prints a message that the file has been sent successfully, but there is no notification on my phone. How can I solve this problem? This notification and file are not reaching my phone? I don't understand where this notification is going.

When the code runs, a file comes to the https://console.firebase.google.com/ >>storage section, but a link and explanation do not come to the notification window of my phone. Does it require a separate setting?

Or is it not possible to send a notification with an icon to the notification window of the android phone with firebase without an android application relationship? If so which GCP (Google Cloud Platform) application should we use to send push notifications?

**Another method, If we want to send a notification to our phone when a new file is uploaded, we can use Cloud Functions to trigger a function when a new file is added to the storage bucket, and use the FCM API to send a notification to our device. But how? Could you revise my shared code this situation? This will be accept a solution.**

Answer (score 0):

The code is currently sending a general notification to all devices that are subscribed to the `price_tracker` topic. Therefore, if you have 10 devices subscribed to the `price_tracker` topic then all of them would receive that same notification which isn't what I think you're expecting. This may be the reason you're not seeing any notification as well because the device that you have did not subscribe to the `price_tracker` topic.

To send the notification directly to a single device, you will have to get the FCM device token which you will pass into the `messaging.Message` function instead of `topic`

For detailed instructions on how to obtain the FCM token in your app, see the Firebase documentation:
[Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#access_the_registration_token)
[iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#access_the_registration_token)

Your code will then look like this

```py
message = messaging.Message(
    notification=messaging.Notification(
        title='Price Tracker Analysis has been finished.',
        body='Click here to view analysis results.',
    ),
    data={
        'url': url
    },
    token='DEVICE_REGISTRATION_TOKEN',
    android=messaging.AndroidConfig(
        ttl=86400,
        notification=messaging.AndroidNotification(
            click_action='DOWNLOAD_PDF'
        )
    )
)

# Send the message to the specified device
response = messaging.send(message)
```

Replace `DEVICE_REGISTRATION_TOKEN` with the FCM registration token of the target device. When you call the messaging.send() method, the push notification will be sent to the specified device.